# Cannot control fan-speed on Acer predator Helios 300

Tags: acer, overheating, fan, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04(but there was same problem on 16.04). I cannot control the fan speed. Ubuntu runs with same fan speed as that when logged out of windows(dual-boot).
I have tried `sensors-detect` but it only enters 'coretemp' into /etc/modules.
Also `pwmconfig` returns the following:
"/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed"
please help!

Comment: I am having same issue. Please let me know if you have found any solution.